# Shrinkwrapping algorithm

Tags: algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry, rhino3d, rhinoceros

I would like to implement a shrinkwrapping algorithm for Rhinoceros 7. I often find myself using the Unified Skin tool in Zbrush to create a single watertight mesh from a collection of overlapping meshes. Which algorithm is this?

Comment: Just mentioning something that might be relevant: https://www.cfdengine.com/newsletter/147/

Comment: Rhino 8 has the ShrinkWrap command: https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/rhino-8-feature-shrinkwrap/149658